# Sublime text can't close window

Tags: sublimetext3

I want to get rid of this annoying window but I don't know how, please help me.
Here's an image:

[image]

The picture shows what I don't want.

Comment: https://gyazo.com/255d086b0563e6ad2a0bff16b7f184eb this is the link sry for linking google

Answer (score 3):

You have to fix your layout:

View > layout > 1 pane